# How do I get a button in python to run a python code when pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt4, beagleboneblack

I am currently working on a program to work with thermocouples that work with a Beagle Bone. The code is in python and when ran as a .py works fine, but my professor wants the program to have a GUI so the underclassmen have an easier time using the program.

```
import xlsxwriter
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import time
ADC.setup()
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('Volt.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col=0

reading = 1
number = input("Enter number of measurements: ")
interv = input("Enter interval time: ")
while number > 0:
    worksheet.write(row, col, reading)
    fraction  = ADC.read("AIN4")
    fraction = ADC.read("AIN4")
    volts = fraction  * 1.8 
    print volts
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, volts)
    time.sleep(interv)
    number=number-1
    row = row + 1
    reading=reading+1

worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Reading Number')
worksheet.write(row, 1, 'Voltage')

workbook.close()
```

Now, how would I make it so when you press button 1 (on the code below) it runs?

Code for GUI:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(633, 378)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 611, 341))
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setLineWidth(0)
        self.label.setMidLineWidth(1)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Beagle Bone Thermocouple Program- Coded by Joshua Baney", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Press for use of two thermocouples", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Press for use of one thermocouple", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">Beagle Bone thermocuple program</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt;\">Coded by Joshua Baney</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt;\">support: joshnbaney@gmail.com</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt;\"><br/></span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt;\"><br/></span></p></body></html>", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a new `class` that will initialize a GUI class:

```
from ui_Form import Ui_Form

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #   here you connect a button to 
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.run_code)

    #   execute the code you want
    def run_code(self):
        code.py #   but better would be to create a method/function for this code or even a class with method to tun
```